# Try to find a HLS server stream live?

Tags: ffmpeg, stream, video-streaming, http-live-streaming

My goal: Stream a live HLS video in browser.

I have in a folder m3u8 files with some .ts. I can play the m3u8 in browser. But this isn't a live stream.
So i try to find a server to stream a HLS in live.
I work on Linux Ubuntu 14.04.

For example:
input /home/master.m3u8 i would like output http://127.0.0.1/master.m3u8
A flash player in browser play http://127.0.0.1/master.m3u8

Thx

Comment: I try `ffmpeg -i bipbop_4x3_variant.m3u8 http://127.0.0.1/mystream.m3u8`
but doesn't work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use any HTTP server such as Nginx, Apache and others to serve your HLS stream.

To create the actual stream you can use `ffmpeg`:

`ffmpeg -re -i <input> /path/to/web/dir/playlist.m3u8`

The `-re` tells it to read the input file at its native framerate. By default the playlist size is 5 but you can change it using `hls_list_size`.

For a complete list of parameters see: https://www.ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-formats.html#hls-1